# How do I check something on an interval asynchronously in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, python-multithreading

Let's say I have a file that I know is going to be updated sometime in the next minute. I want a Python function to fire (roughly) as soon as that happens.

I set up something rudimentary to await that input:

```py
import os, time

modification_time = os.path.getmtime(file)

def wait_for_update(file):
    modified = False
    while not modified:
        if modification_time == os.path.getmtime(file):
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            modified = True
            file_contents = file.read()
```

Theoretically, that should work fine.

However, I'm coming from a Javascript background. In Javascript, a single-threaded language, the equivalent of that function will stop the entire programme until that while loop finishes - and precious seconds of time that could be spent processing other input is wasted.

In Javascript, there's a handy `window.setTimeout()` function that queues up a function to be fired at some point in the future when the main thread is clear of processes. It's not truly asynchronous, it just offsets that operation a little bit into the future, leaving other stuff to happen in the meantime.

So that same process written in recursive JS might look something like this:

```js
function waitForUpdate(file) {
    var modified = false;
    modified = compareFileModificationDates();
    if(modified) {
        modified = true;
        // do other things
    } else {
        setTimeout(waitForUpdate(file), 1000);
    }
}
```

Do I need to do something similar in Python? Or is `time.sleep` fine?

Comment: Can't you make another while-loop where you check if the file is done and if-not, you just do something else in the meanwhile?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock No, this is a function buried in a child script in a py file called from a master script. Your solution would be feasible if this was a simple single-file, single-function deal

Comment: Could you explain what the fundamental problem is here? Is your program blocking because you're waiting or do you want to wait more efficiently?